# how to authenticate user and password using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to authenticate username and password using ruby on rails.

If my authentication is right i need to go some other page. Any advice which type of mechanism should I use ...

Sample code of **Login.html.erb**:

```
<%  form_tag @hello, :validate => true do |f|%>
<tr>
    <td><b>Student Register No <sup>*</sup></b></td>
    <td><%=text_field :user, :name, :placeholder => "Reg.No"%>
        <%=@user.errors.on(:name)%>
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Password</b></td>
    <td><%=text_field :user, :password :placeholder => "Password"% >
        <%=@user.errors.on(:password)%>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b><%=submit_tag "submit"%></b></td>
    <td><b><input type="reset" name="cancel"/></b></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
```

Comment: which rails have you really?

Comment: Get the `devise` gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 1):

Please see this video

authentication from scratch ==> [click](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)

or

Use `devise` gem for authentication [gem](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: `devise`, not `device` ;).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and likely best, way to [manage authentication in Rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication) is to use a pre-packaged solution called [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Devise is a gem, or more specifically, a Rails Engine, which allows you to handle user login & password authentication within your app. It works using the [Warden framework](https://github.com/hassox/rails_warden) to provide a simple way to manage users across your app

Regardless of your rails version, I would *highly* recommend looking into Devise!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the question.
Do you want to create your own user authentication or do you want to know how it works ?

If you want to create your own user authentication, I would recommend [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails).
You should know that there is Rails v3.2 used.